# Yii2 file validation always shows empty

Tags: php, validation, file-upload, yii2

I have a Kartik fileInput in my form and here's how the code for making it looks like:

```
echo $form->field($model, 'images')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
    'options' => ['accept' => 'image/*','multiple' => true]
]);
```

I want to validate the input so that uploading images is required. For that I have the following line in my model:

```
[['images'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg,jpeg']
```

This is the code of my model:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

/**
 * LoginForm is the model behind the login form.
 *
 * @property User|null $user This property is read-only.
 *
 */
class PhonesForm extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public $images;

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{phones}}';
    }

    /**
     * @return array the validation rules.
     */ 
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name', 'price','model','description'], 'required'],
            [['name','model'],'string', 'min' => 3],
            [['description'],'string', 'min' => 25],
            ['price','integer'],
            [['images'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg,jpeg']
        ];
    }

    public function upload()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            $this->images->saveAs('uploads/' . $this->images->baseName . '.' . $this->images->extension);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that is always gives me a validation error saying `Please upload a file.`. How can I fix this problem? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I have updated my controller method and my model.

Controller method:

```
public function actionAdd()
    {
        if (!Yii::$app->user->getIsGuest() && Yii::$app->user->identity->role == 'admin') {

            $model = new PhonesForm();

            if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

                $model->images = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'images');

                if ($model->upload()) {
                    echo "success";
                }
                else{
                    return $this->render('dashboardAdd',[
                        'model' => $model
                    ]);
                }
            }
            else{
                return $this->render('dashboardAdd',[
                    'model' => $model
                ]);
            }   
        }
        else{
            return $this->redirect(['site/index']);
        }
    }
```

Model:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * LoginForm is the model behind the login form.
 *
 * @property User|null $user This property is read-only.
 *
 */
class PhonesForm extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public $images;

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{phones}}';
    }

    /**
     * @return array the validation rules.
     */ 
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name', 'price','model','description'], 'required'],
            [['name','model'],'string', 'min' => 3],
            [['description'],'string', 'min' => 25],
            ['price','integer'],
            [['images'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg,jpeg']
        ];
    }

    public function upload()
    {
        if (!$this->validate()) { 
            return false;
        }
        foreach ($this->images as $image) {
            $image->saveAs('uploads/' . $image->baseName . '.' . $image->extension);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I still have the same issue.

Comment: Please show us the code of the action that handles the file upload.

Comment: It looks like this:
`public function upload()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            $this->images->saveAs('uploads/' . $this->images->baseName . '.' . $this->imageFile->extension);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }`
But the validation is never passed, so it doesn't work.

Comment: what is `$this->imageFile->extension` where is it coming from shouldnt it be `$this->images->extension`?

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this?

Answer (score -1):

Before validation, you must pass uploaded files to the model.
For example, you can do it in your controller

```
$model = new PhonesForm();

if (Yii::$app->request->isPost && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    $model->images = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'images');
    if ($model->save() && $model->upload()) {
        return;
    }
 }
```

But if you want to upload multiple files `upload` method must work with files as an array, for example:

```
public function upload()
{
    if (!$this->validate()) { 
        return false;
    }

    foreach ($this->images as $image) {
        $image->saveAs('uploads/' . $image->baseName . '.' . $image->extension);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to do the validation and upload in a model called `PhonesForm`. I have `use yii\web\UploadedFile;` in my class. How can I do this for my `PhonesForm` model?

Comment: @GrigoryVolkov Can you attach code of your class to the answer?

Comment: I updated the question, will you please take a look.